# Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings')

Tags: android

I can not find what is wrong with the main.xml file

here is the main code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item

        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

The error i face is:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
```

Thanks

Comment: check whether you have string action_settings defined in strings.xml

Comment: In string.xml file you have done spelling mistake. so may be resource no found with '@string/action_settings' :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check your `res/values/strings.xml` and have a look if there is `<string name="action_settings"></string>` value.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

add in ..\res\values\strings.xml

```
<string name="action_settings">Action Settings</string>
```

And Update ..\src\com\example\helloworld\MainActivity.java Line 18 with follows

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.**main**, menu);

it worked for me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to build & refresh your project because maybe the id action_setting is not visible to the R.java file. i have the same error shown but my code was missing + between @ and id

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.amrismail.logintutorial.Main" >
    <item
    android:id=@id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```